# How to stop snakes from exiting the grid in this game?

Tags: python

```
import turtle

def clear_screen(x,y):
    screen.clear()

screen=turtle.getscreen()
screen.onclick(clear_screen)
#imports screen and then clears it when your right click it
   
turtle.getscreen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
jamal = turtle.Turtle()
brett =turtle.Turtle()

for i in range (5):
    t.dot(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()

t.penup()
t.backward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.pendown()

for i in range (5):
    t.dot(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()

t.penup()
t.backward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.pendown()

for i in range (5):
    t.dot(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()

t.penup()
t.backward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.pendown()

for i in range (5):
    t.dot(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()

t.penup()
t.backward(250)
t.right(90)
t.forward(50)
t.left(90)
t.pendown()

for i in range (5):
    t.dot(10)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(50)
    t.pendown()

colora = input("What colour do you choose for your turtle!?")
colorb = input ("What colour do you choose for your turtle player 2?")
jamal.color(colora)
brett.color(colorb)


brett.penup()

brett.goto(200, -200)
brett.pendown()

def w():
    jamal.setheading(90)
    jamal.fd(50)
def s():
    jamal.setheading(270)
    jamal.fd(50)
def a():
    jamal.setheading(180)
    jamal.fd(50)
def d():
    jamal.setheading(0)
    jamal.fd(50)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(w, "w")

screen.onkey(s, "s")

screen.onkey(a, "a")
screen.onkey(d, "d")
```

I have figured out the solution to my last question, but now i really need help with stopping the two movable turtles from going past the boundaries of the grid. I haven't the slightes idea what code i will need to execute this and have searches online for an answer with no prevail. Any help would be appreciated! Thankyou

Comment: Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: line 88, in s
    a.setheading(270)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'setheading'

Comment: because you defined a function named `a` that replaced your variable `a` . I strongly suggest you rename your variables and functions with appropriate and descriptive names. Never name your functions and variables a, b, z... like you do.

Comment: sorry i dont understand. can you explain to me by substiuting what you said into an example

Comment: That isn't the full traceback. In any event -- why are you using the same variable `a` to represent both a turtle and a function? Pick different names.

Comment: you have a line where you do `def a():`  that means that you are creating a function named `a` which will replace your variable named `a`. Don't do that, name your function with a descriptive name of what it does, like `def setHeading180():`. Same for your variables, if `a` represents a turtle, name it `myTurtle`  or `turtle1` for example. You have other turtles named `b` and `t`  which you should also rename to `turtle2` and `turtle3`. You should really do this before implementing more things.

Comment: cheers m8. i got it fixed now. Any idea on how to stop the turtles from leaving the grid

Comment: The turtles leaving the grid is a different question. You should ask another question with your fixed code that solves this one

Comment: i cant post another question for 90 minutes. Could you please help me with this, i really need to do well in this to pass my subject